# Want to assign value in the new column by comparing the other column in pandas data frame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe and has a column name called savings. In that savings, it has a positive and negative value. I want to check if the savings is negative then assign 1 in the new column (need to create a new column name called flag_negative). If the savings is positive assign 0 in the new column. I have a missing value in the savings column which I don't want to do anything. Leave as it is.

I would like to apply loop or any other easy method.

my dataframe name is df

I want to get as follow

Number of rows: 9000

savings     flag_negative

100              0

-76              1

1200             0

- -

  - -

-200               1

500                0

I tried with loop and created new column as flag_ negatvie. But I am getting NONE for all the rows

Below is my code

```
for i in sum['savings']:
    if i>0:
        sum['flag_negative'] = print(0)
    elif i == " ":
        sum['flag_negative'] = print(" ")
    else:
        sum['flag_negative'] = print(1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your dataframe is like this:

```
    savings
0        -4
1       -41
2       174
3      -103
4      -194
5      -160
6       126
7       100
8      -125
9       -71
10     -159
11     -100
12      -30
13      -50
14       83
15      124
16     -123
17      -70
18      -71
19      -29
```

then you can easily filter on positive/negative and assign to a new column like this:

```
df.loc[df.savings < 0, 'flag_negative'] = 1
df.loc[df.savings >= 0, 'flag_negative'] = 0
```

resulting in:

```
    savings  flag_negative
0        -4            1.0
1       -41            1.0
2       174            0.0
3      -103            1.0
4      -194            1.0
5      -160            1.0
6       126            0.0
7       100            0.0
8      -125            1.0
9       -71            1.0
10     -159            1.0
11     -100            1.0
12      -30            1.0
13      -50            1.0
14       83            0.0
15      124            0.0
16     -123            1.0
17      -70            1.0
18      -71            1.0
19      -29            1.0
```

Comment: Loops are generally discouraged with pandas.  They tend to be slow compared with the filtering/masking method shown here.

Comment: Why not just `df.savings.lt(0).astype(int)`